# Calculate a specific curve with specific rotation, c#

Tags: c#, math, curve

I am trying to code for a game I am working on a specific curve with a specific rotation. I am not a great mathematician... At all... Tried searching for solutions for a few hours, but I'm affraid I do not find any solution.

So, a small picture to illustrate first:

[image]

This is an eighth of a circle, radius of 9, beggining is (0,0)

The end is now at about 6.364, -2.636. But I need this same curve, with a 45° direction at the end, but ending at aexactly 6.0,-3.0.

Could any of you show me how to do this? I need to be able to calculate precisly any point on this curve & its exact length. I would suppose using some kind of eliptical math could be a solution? I admit my math class are reaaaly far now and have now good clue for now...

Thank for any possible help

Comment: You may be confusing yourself, _and others_, with your explanation. Is there any way you could re-word the shape you're trying to create, in simplest terms? ie. A quarter circle, of radius 9, beginning at (0,0)

Comment: Thanks Josh, edited as suggested.

Comment: I do have that already. As shown in the image provided. What I need is a different curve that (if I am not mistaken) is not a part of a circle. Starting at (0,0), ending at (6,-3) with a 45° inclination.

Comment: So your requirements are some line to:
- start at (0,0)
- end at (6, -3)
- end with a 45 inclination?

Comment: Exactly yes. Sorry if I was unclear before

Comment: @Garlik: I don't think you need the elliptic curve tag. Read its description: "In mathematics, an elliptic curve is a smooth, projective algebraic curve of genus one, on which there is a specified point O." Elliptic curves are used for cryptography and number theoretical applications... not this.

Comment: There are probably many curves which could satisfy your requirement. A circle definitely won't, since the radius at the top is 9, but at the end it's 6 * sqrt(2).

Comment: By "45-degree direction", do you mean *clockwise/anticlockwise* with respect to the tangent at the start of the curve, or the X-axis, or any other reference axis?

Comment: meowgoesthedog, my math words are unprecise, especially in english.

If you look at the provided picture, the start of the curve is 0°, the end is 45° (or -45?) as it is an eighth of a circle. I do need this same inclination, but at a different location (6,-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a quadratic curve which sastisfies your requirement:

```
f(x) = -1/12 x^2 + 9
```

Copy the following into https://www.desmos.com/calculator to see it:

```
-\frac{1}{12}x^2+9
```

f'(x) would be -1/6x, so when x=6, the derivative would be -1, which corresponds to a -45° inclination. There are probably infinite curves that satisfy your requirement but if my calculus isn't too rusty this is one of them.

I tried to fit an ellipse with foci starting at `y=6` [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/foiat7zclz) and starting at `y=9` [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hrcdhsnjnu) to your points but the slope doesn't look like 45°.
Also starting at any height k, [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xeqev82ae2) doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Perect indeed! Thanks a lot for your time.
I was hoping for something a bit more 'roundish', but I suppose this will do for now.

I think I should read a bit more on Bezier curves If I want something else :)

Thanks again

Comment: I tried with an ellipse but the slope doesn't work out.. check the link on the edited answer.

Comment: Anyway if you want something rounder I think you should look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34973466/creating-a-curve-between-two-points-each-with-normalized-vectors

Comment: You have to satisfy the requirements of f(0) = 0, f(6) = -3, and f'(6) = -1. Once you solve the quadratic equation, you get what he got ^^^

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you've fully understood the question I asked in the comments about the "inclination" angle. So I will give a *general* case solution, where you have an explicit *tangent vector* for the end of the curve. (You can calculate this using the inclination angle; if we clarify what you mean by it then I will be happy to edit with a formula to calculate the tangent vector if necessary)

---

Let's draw a diagram of how the setup can look:

[image]

(Not 100% accurate)

`A` and `B` are your fixed points. `T` is the **unit** tangent vector. `r` and `C` are the radius and center of the arc we need to calculate.

The angle `θ` is given by the angle between `BA` and `T` minus `π/2` radians (90 degrees). We can calculate it using the dot product:

[image]

The (signed) distance from the center of `AB` to `C` is given by:

[image]

Note that this is negative for the case on the right, and positive for the left. The radius is given by:

[image]

(You can simplify by substituting and using a cosine addition rule, but I prefer to keep things in terms of variables in the diagram). To obtain the point `C`, we need the perpendicular vector to `AB` (call it `n`):

[image]

Now that we have the *radius* and *center* of the circular arc, we still need to determine *which* direction we are moving in, i.e. whether we are moving *clockwise* or *anti-clockwise* when going from `A` to `B`. This is a simple test, using the *cross-product*:

[image]

If this is negative, then `T` is as in the diagram, and we need to move *clockwise*, and vice versa. The length of the arc `l`, and the angular displacement `γ` when we move by a distance `x` along the arc:

[image]

Nearly there! Just one more step - we need to work out how to rotate the point `A` by angle `γ` around point `C`, to get the point we want (call it `D`):

[image]

(Adapted from this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix))

---

Now for some code, in case the above was confusing (it probably was!):

```
public Vector2 getPointOnArc(Vector2 A, Vector2 B, Vector2 T, double x)
{
    // calculate preliminaries
    Vector2 BA = B - A;
    double d = BA.Length();
    double theta = Math.Acos(Vector2.DotProduct(BA, T) / d) - Math.PI * 0.5;

    // calculate radius
    double r = d / (2.0 * Math.Cos(theta));

    // calculate center 
    Vector2 n = new Vector2(BA.y, -BA.x);
    Vector2 C = 0.5 * (A + B + n * Math.Tan(theta));

    // calculate displacement angle from point A
    double l = (Math.PI - 2.0 * theta) * r;
    double gamma = (2.0 * Math.PI * x) / l;

    // sign change as discussed
    double cross = T.x * BA.y - T.y * BA.x;
    if (cross < 0.0) gamma = -gamma;

    // finally return the point we want
    Vector2 disp = A - C;
    double c_g = Math.Cos(gamma), s_g = Math.Sin(gamma);
    return new Vector2(disp.X * c_g + disp.Y * s_g + C.X,
                       disp.Y * c_g - disp.X * s_g + C.Y);
}
```

Comment: He also said that the starting angle is 0° so while this is pretty amazing stuff I don't think it answers the OPs question.

Comment: @AlexDev hmm yes, I don't think it's possible (in general) to fix both end-points *and* both tangent orientations (if the curve were to be circular). I'll wait to see what OP thinks

Comment: Big thanks for your detailed explanations. Indeed, as AlexDev suggests, this does not solve my precise problem. The curve I am looking for can not be circular. The closest circular curve I have is the one attached in the OP screenshot, but is does not match my criteria of endpoint (6,-3), though it does have the correct inclination.

Comment: I am trying to create the curve I am looking for from 2 control points (0,0) & (6,-3) and 2 vectors (1,0) and (0.5,0.5). Am now at work and cant test my results yet. The problem I think I will be facing with what I am currently working on is finding the theorical exact length of the curve I am creating. Though I think I could work arround it by creating lots (thousands, if not millions) of points between those control points and mesuring the distance between each.

Comment: @Garlik in that case you might be looking for a *bezier curve* (At least cubic order)

Comment: I have indeed tried them. Having the start & end positions precise is easy, but having them with the correct orientation is harder.

I actualy think quadratic bezier curve is better. I should test the control point to be at (3,-1.5), I suppose it will give me the correct curve, but doubt it will have the correct vectors needed (1,0) & (0.5,0.5) at start & end point respectivly

Comment: @Garlik quadratic curves only have one control point, so it's only really a coincidence that you can find one to suit your setup. To calculate the control points just add some distance times the tangent to the endpoints; these two distances also control the shape of the curve

Comment: I'll give them another try indeed.
Another problem I have with Bezier, is that its hard to find accurate length of the curve. I think one can only aproximate it by mesuring distance between each point calculated and adding them. If enough points calculated, the aproximation can be quite precise though.

Comment: @Garlik you might want a more *adaptive* method to calculate the length, i.e. longer distances between points for parts with small curvature, and vice versa.

Comment: ok, got what I need. Cubic Bezier with: (0,0), (2.8,0), (4.5, -1.5), (6,-3) gives a curve I like.

I splited this curve in half a million points (not same size as Bezier). Found that the aproximated length was ~6.92. Then tried to find points on the curve every 0.01, using the previously calculated half million points. Thus got 692 points. Biggest error is 0.00007345. I can accept this. My reference is a meter, so 7% of a milimeter error is ok.

This is all to create a curved train track for trains to move on. The small speed error when on curve will not be visible I guess.
Thanks again

Comment: @Garlik I'd be careful about using too many points - if the distance between a pair of points is too small then you could get underflow when calculating it (Pythagoras squares the coordinate deltas). Seems like your results were fine though

Comment: Yes, saw that indeed, when calculating 1M points, the total length of the curve started to shrink in comparaison to the 1/2M points length. Wich is not logic. So I sticked with 1/2M :)

Too bad one eighth of a circle did not work for me, I could have completely skiped pre-saving points on the curve and could have easily calculated exact positions anywhere on the curve on the fly. Bezier gives more precision in drawing the curve, but is less precise if you want to move along the curve and calculate hundreds of similar positions 60times per second...